# How to retrieve HTTP REST METHOD of current service at Run time in WSO2 AM Sequence?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to retrieve HTTP REST METHOD(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS) in WSO2 Api Manager's Sequence at runtime? I tried to $ctx:REST_METHOD which returns 'null' value.

```
  <sequence name="ec_rest_dynamic_ep" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <property expression="$ctx:REST_METHOD" name="restmethod"
    scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <log>
    <property expression="get-property('restmethod')" name="*******************REST_METHOD***********"/>
  </log>
</sequence>
```

Basically, HTTP REST METHOD value of current service & URL context of that service needed to identify the service in order redirect the service to its endpoint dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following property.

```
<property name="Http_Method" expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD')"/>
```

You can find more useful properties in [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/master/modules/distribution/resources/customsequences/in/debug_in_flow.xml).

Comment: the "more useful properties [1]" link is broken.. any other link for these properties?

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v2.1.0-rc5/modules/distribution/resources/customsequences/in/debug_in_flow.xml

Answer (score 0):

@Pubci's answer is correct. Here is another way.

```
<property name="Method" scope="transport" expression="$ctx:api.ut.HTTP_METHOD"/>
```

Some other properties can be found [here](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html).